# Breaking down a GOD class to single responsible classes

Tags: oop, kotlin, design-patterns

**Problem:**

I have a GOD class in my project which consists of more than 40 to 50 functions that belong to different services.

**What I want to achieve:**

I want to move unique functions to dedicated subclasses and common functions to a parent class. So that all the functions that belong to a particular feature belongs to a dedicated class. Now the GOD class is injected in many classes.

Can someone suggest me a design pattern where I don’t have to individually inject all these `SubClass` but a factory which will give the instances of these SubClasses and also provide access to the common functions which are in the parent class. Is it possible?

```
class GodClass {
    fun common(){}
    fun a(){}
    fun b(){}
    fun c(){}
    fun d(){}
}
abstract class ParentClass {
   fun common(){}
}
class SubClass1: ParentClass {
    fun a(){}
    fun d(){}
}
class SubClass2: ParentClass {
    fun b(){}
    fun c(){}
}
```

Comment: I thought the `GodClass` is already either the factory you're looking for, or a `Mediator`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce can you explain how GodClass can act as a `Factory` ?

Comment: It's probably not a factory, but it can definitely be a mediator, as I mentioned above.

Comment: It would really help to suggest better design if the example wasn't abstract, but you'd present an example that's related to real life.

Comment: The GOD class is an AnalyticsTracking class basically. I am just trying to break down the GOD class into different mini classes with dedicated analytics functions for a particular feature.
There are common analytics functions used by different features in the project.
I am not overriding any functions. I am just copying all the unique analytics functions to their dedicated feature classes and moving common analytics functions to a common class.

Comment: @JakubZalas solved the problem using Facade design pattern.